# Worded linear congruence problem-Days/Years

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The Melbourne cup is run every year on the first Tuesday in November. The US presidential elections are held every four years on the day after the first Monday in November. George W. Bush was elected on Tuesday 7 November 2000 and “Brew” won the Melbourne cup the same day. By solving an appropriate congruence, find the first date in this millenium on which there was/will be a US presidential election but no Melbourne cup.

I'm ok with solving systems of linear congruences but can't seem to get the hang of these worded questions. Where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : We have to find the earliest year after $2000$, such that the first Monday of November in this year is not followed by the first Tuesday of November in the same year. So, the $1st$ November must fall on a Tuesday. Aditionally, the number denoting the year must be divisible by $4$.

Comment: Another hint : At $2000$, the first November was a Wednesday, at $2004$, it was a Monday, at $2008$, it was a Saturday. Do you see the pattern ? If not, look at the calendar of the current year :)

Comment: Thank you! I understand now